# How to convert an ascii code to an actual character in Maya

Tags: character-encoding, ascii, maya, mel

I am currently developing a mel script in Maya, but am unable to print a character based on its ascii code (for example 65 should print 'A'), as the char(xx) command in other languages.

How can I achieve that ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other way is to use a python command inside MEL script:

```
$n = 65;
print("BB" + python("chr("+$n+")") + "CC");
```

result:

```
BBACC
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is looking for the same answer, the way I finally implemented it is to create a string containing all charaters and then picking the right character in the string using the substring command.